# Continu my music after a pause in just_audio plugin

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I use the plugin **just_audio**
How can I continu my music after to do a pause? please.

```
void _play() {
    audioPlayer.setAsset("assets/applause.mp3");
    audioPlayer.play();
  }
void _pause() async {
    await audioPlayer.pause();
  }
  void _rePlay() async {
    ?????????????????????????
  }
```

Comment: Have You tried `audioPlayer.play()`; ?

Comment: thank you ;) I think play it's restart in beginning thank you a Lot for your good answer

Answer (score 3):

In general, after calling `pause`, call `play` to "resume".

In your case, you should NOT set the asset file again. This resets the process.

Below is your code, pasted from your question:

```
void _play() { // BAD EXAMPLE
  audioPlayer.setAsset("assets/applause.mp3"); // <-- PROBLEM
  audioPlayer.play();
}
```

You should move `setAsset` call elsewhere, like in `init state`.

Comment: An example would be so valueble

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `audioPlayer.play()`. This works exactly like the play button in a music app, while `pause()` works exactly like the pause button in a music app.

It is designed this way so that you can simply wire up your play and pause buttons directly to these player methods.

For example, here are the play/pause buttons from the just_audio example app:

```dart
// Play button:
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
  onPressed: audioPlayer.play,
)
// Pause button:
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
  onPressed: audioPlayer.pause,
)
```

You can just alternate calls to `play()`/`pause()`/`play()`/`pause()`. Note the left side of this state diagram from the README:

[image]